# Flask Application: Difficulty Linking HTML to CSS and JavaScript in Separate Folders

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I'm building a Flask application with the following structure:

```
project_folder/
│-- templates/
│   └-- index.html
│-- static/
│   └-- styles.css
│   └-- script.js
│-- backend/
    └--backend.py
```

I've attempted using the url_for function in Flask to generate the correct URLs for the CSS and JavaScript files, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
```

However, this doesn't seem to link the files properly. I expected the styles and scripts to be applied accordingly, but it's not working as intended.

this is my backend.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import openai
from openai.error import OpenAIError
import json
import re

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

openai.api_key = ""
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('templates/index.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please put `backend.py` in the question

Comment: i put my backend.py

Comment: my answer helped you?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `render_template()` it get the files from the *templates* directory.

Check this out: [*Templates Documentation*](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/tutorial/templates/)

So, if your `backend.py` is in the *backend* folder, **it will search for the files in *backend/templates***! The same goes for the *static* folder.

You have 2 solutions:

1. Move `backend.py` to the main directory
2. Change the *static*  and *tamplate*  directories configuration.

If you choose the solution number 2, you can do this way:

```py
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../templates', static_folder='../static')
```

Comment: it did not work.

Comment: Sorry, I've improved my answer.